# ADB Backup - Unknown backup flag

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb, backup

I am trying to do an ADB backup of a device. The device is seen and able to communicate with the ADB.

The code I want to run is:

```
adb backup -shared -apk -all
```

After running the above command the response is:

```
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.
```

Then the command terminates. Without any prompts on the mobile.

When I ran `adb logcat`, I got a weird response in the logcat, here it is:

```
10-23 13:10:09.135 11119 11119 D bu: Beginning: backup
10-23 13:10:09.137 11119 11119 W bu: Unknown backup flag -apk:-shared:-all
10-23 13:10:09.137 11119 11119 E bu: no backup packages supplied and neither -shared nor -all given
10-23 13:10:09.137 11119 11119 D bu: Finished.
```

It seems that the ADB isn't recognising -apk or -shared as flags.

I am able to run:

```
adb backup -all
```

So the phone is working and the ADB is able to run backups.

Anyone seen this before and have a solution?

**EDIT 1**

Running the following:

```
adb backup '-apk -shared -all'
```

Seems to then run the following command:

```
10-23 13:31:40.598  2954  6688 V BackupManagerService: Requesting full backup: apks=true obb=false shared=true all=true system=true pkgs=[Ljava.lang.String;@73faafb
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution was to put all the options in the '' quotation marks, f.e.:

```
adb backup '-apk -obb -shared -all -system' -f /path/to/backup.ab
```

Answer (score 0):

try
adb backup "-apk -shared -all " -f c:\Users**user**\backup.ab

you need to put the " " like i did . Not ' ' like our frineds did above

Comment: If you are repeating what someone else's answer is you should just make a comment or even edit their answer to correct the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remedy this in Windows OS with properly placed quotes...

```
adb backup "-apk -shared -all -system" -f backup20170508.ab
```

Take note, the process failed when I tried to have my file path (-f) start from C:\ and traverse through Users\ to my personal folder due to permission issues.  Deposit the backup in the same folder as the adb executable and just move it when you're done.